# Is there a power shell command to add a zipped folder to a location on a network location?

Tags: windows, powershell, ftp, ftp-client

I am very new to Powershell but have learned that is a very powerful tool to master. I am attempting to take a folder from a location on my PC, Zip it and then paste it into a folder located on a network drive. I have figured out how to create a zip of a folder and send it to a location on my machine but can not figure out how to send it to anywhere else.

Is this the way to go about it?
Is this even possible?

I have been able to use
"Compress-Archive -Path C:\ProgramData\Microsoft C:\users\MYACT\Desktop\Folder"

(I am using goolge as an example because i am not sure if i can put the actual location on here )
I am attempting to use (but failing)

"Compress-Archive -Path C:\ProgramData\Microsoft ftp://ftp.google.com\parent\Sub"

When Run the command i receive

Compress-Archive : The path 'ftp:\ftp.google.com\parentFolder\SubFolder' either does not exist or is not a valid 
system path.

Comment: your error answers your question. [*grin*] FTP is not a valid _system_ path. you will need to compress to a _system_ path [`d:\data` or `\\SysName\ShareName\data`] and then copy to the FTP location.

Comment: @Matt compress the file locally and then Use Copy-Item to send it to the ftp location

Comment: There's a Powershell provider for FTP https://github.com/Arnavion/PsFtpProvider which theoretically could be used to create archives directly on FTP. Although I've never used it myself.